# Does select, input and label elements have height property?

Tags: html, css, select, label, height

The structure of my markup looks something like this:

```
<div id="outerdiv">
    <div>
        Some text <select>...options...</select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input><label><input><label>...
    </div>
    <div>
        Some text <select>...otions...</select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The text is bold, the `select` tags have their default styling, and the `label` tags are styled as below and all take up space on the page. (The `input` has `display:none`.) However unless the `#outerdiv` is explicitly given a height, it collapses; if a 1px border is applied, it makes a straight horizontal line from which the other styled elements appear to "hang."

Why is this / what is happening here?

Edit: All the inner divs are floated left, and the labels are styled as such:

```
.CheckLabels{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 7%;
    height: 45px;
}
```

No other relevant styles are applied as far as I can tell.

Comment: Your markup for inputs and labels is incorrect. I'm not sure why you've included '.CheckLabels { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does select, input and label elements have height property?

To declare 'height', the element has to be either display: "block" or "inline-block" -

```
.thing {
  display: block; /* or */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px; /* 95% of the time.. you should NOT declare a height */
  /* but this will work */
}
```

(real question)

> Why does my parent Element collapse when I float it's children?

When you 'float' elements, it takes them out of the traditional *flow* - and so you have to use a "clear-fix." [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix)

You can also use `overflow: hidden;` or a border to trick it back into order. Overflow hidden used to have some side-effects... but I don't think that's a concern these days...

```css
.parent {
  background: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden; /* but really - you should use a clearfix */
}

.parent div {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="parent">
  <div>
    Some text
    <select>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="thing-1">Input label</label>
    <input type="text" id="thing-1">
  </div>

  <div>
    Some text
    <select>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful explanation and reference! Experimenting with your code and reading this now, I see the issue. (Also - agreed on the question. I did try to change the title to something closer to what you named, but for some reason the edit was declined.)